# Python numpy array multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product, array-broadcasting

If I have to arrays X (X has n rows and k columns) and Y (Y has n rows and q columns) how do I multiply the two in the vector form, such that I obtain array Z with following characteristics:

```
Z[0]=X[:,0]*Y
Z[1]=X[:,1]*Y
Z[2]=X[:,2]*Y
...
Z[K-1]=X[:,k-1]*Y
Z[K]=X[:,k]*Y

for c in range(X.shape[1]):
    Z[c]=X[:,c].dot(Y)
```

Comment: What's the final shape of `Z`?  (k,)?  (k,q)?  Are you summing over the `n` size?  Details please.   May be even a small 2x3x4 example so we are sure we understand you.

Comment: final shape of Z is (k,q). I will try posting loop version shortly if that may help.

Comment: Please see the loop version added above.

Comment: See my answer for the kind of test case that we like to see.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, and almost no thinking:

```
Z=np.einsum('nk,nq->kq',X,Y)
```

I could also write it with `np.dot`, with a transpose or two.  `np.dot` does the matrix sum over the last dim of the 1st and 2nd to last of 2nd

```
Z = np.dot(X.T, Y)
```

=================

```
In [566]: n,k,q=2,3,4
In [567]: X=np.arange(n*k).reshape(n,k)
In [568]: Y=np.arange(n*q).reshape(n,q)
In [569]: Z=np.einsum('nk,nq->kq',X,Y)
In [570]: Z
Out[570]: 
array([[12, 15, 18, 21],
       [16, 21, 26, 31],
       [20, 27, 34, 41]])
In [571]: Z1=np.empty((k,q))
In [572]: Z1=np.array([X[:,c].dot(Y) for c in range(k)])
In [573]: Z1
Out[573]: 
array([[12, 15, 18, 21],
       [16, 21, 26, 31],
       [20, 27, 34, 41]])
In [574]: X.T.dot(Y)
Out[574]: 
array([[12, 15, 18, 21],
       [16, 21, 26, 31],
       [20, 27, 34, 41]])
```